# how to make double looping with codeigniter

Tags: loops, codeigniter

I have table like this :

[image]

But I have some trouble, my data in number not looping just showing `3`, I want make my table change like this :

[image]

change all `3` to `3,1,1,0,1`

My Query like this :

```
foreach ($list as $field) {
   $row[] = $field->d_point;
   foreach ($all_comparison as $all) {
      $row[] = $all['count_states'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, never ever post a code on an image, since it's hard for us to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue you're facing, and you could get a [downvote for using image of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Just try to copy and paste the codes.

Comment: explain what  $list and $all_comparison are ??

Comment: $all_comparison is a query like this `$this->db->select('count(CASE WHEN states = "Pending" THEN "Refund" WHEN states = "On Process" THEN "Refund" WHEN states = "Complete" THEN "Refund" END ) AS count_states'); $this->db->from('table'); $this->db->group_by('number'); $all = $this->db->get(); return $all->result_array();` and then $list is array value of delivery_point, for example is Kantor Pusat

Comment: query for my model and then I called in Controller so i make a variable like this, `$all_comparison = $this->my_model->name_function_query()`